# Lucene for finding most frequent words or word groups

Tags: java, lucene

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get frequently occuring phrases with Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138928/how-to-get-frequently-occuring-phrases-with-lucene)

I need to find most occuring words or word groups in an index which means most occuring text might be the word itself or a word group. Much similar to twitters trending topic (without hashtag entities ofcourse). Does Lucene provide some sort of method to do so or how can I achieve this in a massive data. If the question is unclear I can give examples to be more specific. I'm using java by the way and Lucene 3.5.

And a quick edit the "word group" can contain max 3 words. Let's say in a big text I have the word "is" 500 times "weather" 100 times "nice" 300 times and the word group "weather is nice" 90 times. I need to find if the occurence of "weather is nice" is important for me. And of course I need to look every indexed word...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find most occurring sequences of consecutive tokens of maximum length 3, the problem can be seen as a search for most frequent N-grams, as discussed in the question [How to get frequently occurring phrases with Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138928/how-to-get-frequently-occuring-phrases-with-lucene)

In your case you probably don't need Solr, see [this little code](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/11/02/writing-a-token-n-grams-analyzer-in-few-lines-of-code-using-lucene/), you just have to count each of the generated N-grams and keep the ones appearing a number of times greater than a desired threshold.
The problem of counting efficiently these Ngrams is more difficult. If they aren't a lot (e.g. less tham 1~2M) you can just use an HashMap.
If there's a greater amount you can try with the interesting count min sketch algorithm, there's an [implementation](https://github.com/clearspring/stream-lib) but personally I've never used it and don't know how good it is.