# Find frequent phrases in text

Tags: lucene

Is there a way to search for frequent phrases with `Lucene`?

I'm searching successfully for frequent words:

```
TermStats[] ts = HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(reader, 20, fieldName, comparator);
```

but this brings single words, and I'm looking for a way to search for frequent two (or any number) word combinations.

To clarify, I'm not looking for top two words I know of (for example fast and car) but top two frequent word combinations. So if my text is "this is a fast car and this is also a fast car" I'll get as a result that "fast car" and "this is" are the top two word combinations.

I looked at the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138928/how-to-get-frequently-occuring-phrases-with-lucene) but it offers a solution with `solr` and I'm looking for something with `Lucene`, and in any case the relevant link is broken.

EDIT: following femtoRgon's comment here's some code from my `Analyzer`. Is this where the `ShingleFilter` should be added? It doesn't seem to work as my output looks like this:

```
ed d 
d 
d   p
 p
 p pl  
pl
pl le
```

What I need is for the output to include pairs of full words.

Here's my `createComponents` method:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader, 2, 2);     
    ShingleFilter sf = new ShingleFilter(source, 2, 2);

    TokenStreamComponents tsc = new TokenStreamComponents(source, sf);  
    return tsc;
}
```

EDIT2: I changed the `NGramTokenizer` to `StandardTokenizer` following femtoRgon's comment and now I'm getting full words, but I don't need the single words, just the pairs.

This is the code:

```
Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader);        
ShingleFilter sf = new ShingleFilter(source, 2, 2);
```

Note the `2, 2` which according to the documents should generate min words of 2, and max words of 2. But in fact it generates this output:

```
and
and other
other
other airborne
airborne
airborne particles
```

So how do I get rid of the single words and get this output?

```
and other
other airborne
airborne particles
```

Comment: [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) is definitely still around, and is my first thought, as well.

Comment: @femtoRgon cool, thanks, I'll give it a try. But how do I then go about getting the most frequent ones?

Comment: `HighFreqTerms` should work just fine.  You index shingles of the appropriate sizes, which gives you multi-word terms in the index, then you just check for the high frequency ones.

Comment: @femtoRgon I edited the question to reflect my attempt at using the ShingleFilter. It doesn't seem to work but maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: `NGramTokenizer` is not a good tokenizer to use with `ShingleFilter`.  You'll want to use something that separates into words, `StandardTokenizer`, for instance.

Comment: @femtoRgon ok, cool, this gives me full words. But I still want to get rid of the single words. I edited my question (EDIT2) with the new info.

Comment: [setOutputUnigrams](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html#setOutputUnigrams(boolean))

Comment: Cool, thanks. if you write this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my full `Analyzer` class that does the job. Note that the `TokenStreamComponents` method is where the `ShingleFilter` is declared following femtoRgon excellent comments to my question. Just put in your own string, specify `minWords` and `maxWords` and run it.

```
public class RMAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    public static String someString = "some string";
    private int minWords = 2;
    private int maxWords = 2;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RMAnalyzer rma = new RMAnalyzer(2, 2);
        rma.findFrequentTerms();
        rma.close();
    }


    public RMAnalyzer(int minWords, int maxWords) { 
        this.minWords = minWords;
        this.maxWords = maxWords;
    }

    public void findFrequentTerms() {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(someString);
        try {
            TokenStream tokenStream = tokenStream("title", sr);
            OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
            CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
            tokenStream.reset();

            while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
                String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
                System.out.println(term);
            }                       
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader);        
        ShingleFilter sf = new ShingleFilter(source, minWords, maxWords);
        sf.setOutputUnigrams(false); // makes it so no one word phrases out in the output.
        sf.setOutputUnigramsIfNoShingles(true); // if not enough for min, show anyway.

        TokenStreamComponents tsc = new TokenStreamComponents(source, sf);  
        return tsc;
    }
}
```